# Php/Mysql Export data from two tables

Tags: php, excel, export

I need to export data from two tables Php/Mysql to Excel or CSV file. I try with Union All but I get data in one cell I need next format:

```
Name:   Age (from another table)
Levan   22
Dito    35
Giorgi  46
```

I receive next:

```
Name:
Levan   
Dito    
Giorgi
22
35
46
```

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.csv');

    //connection
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    if(!$con) {
        echo "Error connection";
    }

    //select db
    $select_db = mysql_select_db('database', $con);
    if(!$select_db) {
        echo "Error to select database";
    }

    mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);

    //Mysql query to get records from datanbase
    $user_query = mysql_query('SELECT Amount FROM Credit UNION ALL SELECT username FROM User');

    //While loop to fetch the records
    $contents = "Amount \t username\n";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query)) {      
        $contents.=$row['Amount']."\t";
        $contents.=$row['username']."\n";       
    }

    $contents_final = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
    print $contents_final;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
Credit.Amount,
User.username
FROM
Credit
INNER JOIN Users ON Credit.username = Users.username
```

The problem was the user columns were different in each table

```
credit->UserID
User: username
```

try this:

```
SELECT
Credit.Amount,
User.username
FROM
Credit
INNER JOIN Users ON Credit.UserID = Users.username
```

Comment: It gives me just titles "Amount and username", but no data :(

Comment: Can you tell me your skype id?

Comment: I prefer not to engage via Skype. If you post your table schema here, with some sample data, or use sqlfiddle, I will do my best to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I got only 20 Amount records. :(

Comment: SELECT Credit.Amount, User.username FROM Credit INNER JOIN User ON Credit.UserID = User.username 

with this I got result Thank you very, much!!!

But one problem is that it exports only 19 records. How should I get all records?

Comment: 200 79skola@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
200 777dondo777@mail.ru
50 1giorgi@bk.ru
150 1giorgi@bk.ru
50 1giorgi@bk.ru
50 1giorgi@bk.ru
50 1giorgi@bk.ru
150 1giorgi@bk.ru
200 1giorgi@bk.ru
50 84misha84@mail.ru
196 999ckito75@mail.ru
194 999ckito75@mail.ru
100 4499gela@mail.ru

The result

Comment: Everything works perfect except: There is only 19 record and it's the same records 5 times. I mean: rezo@geo.ge rezo@geo.ge....

Comment: Is this a one-to-many relationship? Are there multiple records in the child table for each record in the parent table? If so, are you wanting to return each child record, or what?

Comment: SELECT Credit.ID, Credit.Amount, Credit.CreditStartDate, Credit.CreditEndDate, User.name, User.Surename, User.username FROM Credit INNER  JOIN User ON Credit.UserID = User.id WHERE Credit.CreditStatusID=7 --- Works great. Thank you Len_D